# Would lifting the pads off of the display and camera connector kill a RP?

Tags: gpio, boot

Tried to remove some I/O that i dont need from my RP3 A+ to fit in a mobile project.

Ive done this before on my RP3 B with great success. But I wasnt to gentle when removing the display and camera connectors and this caused some of the pads to come off as well and one of the traces to the camera was still attached to the pad.

I tested the pi after the removal of those items, plus the GPIO pins and the Pi will not boot past the GPU test screen (rainbow splash image)

Didnt think this would cause such an issue, as the camera and display ribbons are not that important.

Comment: you probably broke a trace that loops through to another part of the RPi

Comment: Did you test the Pi before removing any connectors?

Answer (score 1):

Those connectors contain ground and power lines.  I would think that shorting those lines could effectively destroy a Pi.